# must call setup() that takes a context and fragmentmanager - Rendering issue

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change my layout style using 'Design' option on android studio.
I get an error, saying that:

*Exception raised during rendering: Must call setup() that takes a Context and FragmentManager (Details)*

I can't understand what can cause this issue to occur, because when I run my app I can see the layout properly but can't edit it.

My class and layout are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_page_product_name"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/nike_show"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:background="@null"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,RtlSymmetry"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/item_page_item_des"
        android:layout_width="326dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/item_page_product_des"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/item_page_product_name"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/item_page_item_id" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/item_page_item_id"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/item_page_product_name"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/item_page_pager"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="213dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/item_page_product_des"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabsHostItem"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="325dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/item_page_pager">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    tools:ignore="UselessParent">
                    <!--<TextView-->
                    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
                    <!--android:text="@string/this_is_tab_1" />-->
                </FrameLayout>

                <!--<LinearLayout-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/tab2"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:orientation="vertical">-->
                <!--<TextView-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:text="@string/this_is_tab_2" />-->

                <!--</LinearLayout>-->

                <!--<LinearLayout-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/tab3"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:orientation="vertical">-->
                <!--<TextView-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:text="@string/this_is_tab_3" />-->

                <!--</LinearLayout>-->
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Class:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.goldbergtom.cricket.adapters.ViewPagerAdapter;
import com.goldbergtom.cricket.fragments.DescriptionFragment;

import controller.ControllerDao;

public class ItemPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    ViewPager viewPager;
    PagerAdapter adapter;
    int[] flag;

    private LinearLayout mGallery;
    private int[] mImgIds;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView;

    private ImageButton back;
    private ImageButton www;
    private ImageButton settings;

    private TextView productMainTitle;
    private TextView productId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_page);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);


        productMainTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.item_page_product_name);
        productId = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.item_page_product_des);
        // productMainTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.item_page_product_name);
        // productMainTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.item_page_product_name);


        String pMT = ControllerDao.currentSessionUser.getProducts()[0].get_title();
        String pid = ControllerDao.currentSessionUser.getProducts()[0].getId();

        productMainTitle.setText(pMT);
        productId.setText(pid);




        // TODO : yahav - remove the comments on the following code and look what it does

//        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
//        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
//        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
//
//        View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cricket_action_bar, null);
//
//        actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
//        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
//
//        back = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_back);
//        back.setOnClickListener(backButtonFromItemActivity);
//
//        www = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_www);
//        www.setOnClickListener(wwwButtonFromItemActivity);
//
//        settings = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_settings1);
//        settings.setOnClickListener(settingsButtonFromItemActivity);
//
        flag = new int[] { R.drawable.ic_1 , R.drawable.ic_2 , R.drawable.ic_3 };

        // Locate the ViewPager in viewpager_main.xml
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.item_page_pager);
        // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(ItemPageActivity.this,  flag);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabsHostItem);

//        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
//        android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
//        ft.commit();

        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("DESCRIPTION",null),DescriptionFragment.class,null);

        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("HISTORY",null),DescriptionFragment.class,null);

        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("ALERTS",null),DescriptionFragment.class,null);

        //Tab 1
//        TabHost.TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("DESCRIPTION");
//        spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
//        spec.setIndicator("Tab One");
//        host.addTab(spec);
//
//        //Tab 2
//        spec = host.newTabSpec("HISTORY");
//        //spec.setContent(R.layout.fragment_description);
//        spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
//        spec.setIndicator("Tab Two");
//        host.addTab(spec);
//
//        //Tab 3
//        spec = host.newTabSpec("ALERTS");
//        spec.setContent(R.id.tab3);
//        spec.setIndicator("Tab Three");
//        host.addTab(spec);

        // CricketDao.GetDataTask gdt = new CricketDao.GetDataTask();
//        String s = null;
//        JSONObject jObject = null, subject = null;
//        JSONArray arr = null;
//        String title=null;

//        try {
//            // TODO : Place resonse as USER object to const
//            s = gdt.execute("https://cricketweb.herokuapp.com/checkLogin").get();
//        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_item_activity, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()){

            // when clicking on the URL icon, it will open the product page through browser.
            case R.id.action_web:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
                return true;

            // when clicking on delete item it will delete the item from wish list and go back to wish list page.
            case R.id.delete_item:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, WishListActivity.class));
                return true;

            // when clicking on purchased item, it will stay on this activity and change on DB from 0 to 1 (help us with adaptation)
            case R.id.purchased_item:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
                return true;

            // when clicking on settings, it will give the user another view of settings option.
            case R.id.action_settings:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
                return true;

            // when clicking on back icon it will go back to previous screen.
            case R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    View.OnClickListener backButtonFromItemActivity = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "backButtonFromItemActivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener wwwButtonFromItemActivity = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wwwButtonFromItemActivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    View.OnClickListener settingsButtonFromItemActivity = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "settingsButtonFromItemActivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    private void initData()
    {

        mImgIds = new int[] { R.drawable.ic_1, R.drawable.ic_2, R.drawable.ic_3,R.drawable.ic_4
        };
    }

    public void toggle_contents(View v){
        new DescriptionFragment().toggle_contents(v);
    }

    public void toggle_contents2(View view) {
        new DescriptionFragment().toggle_contents2(view);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This rendering error occurs because the android studio layout renderer still uses the deprecated setup() method. there's actually an open issue about this [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=229226)
If setup properly like you have it will work as intended when you run the app. the only downside is that you will not get to see the rendered view on the editor until the android team posts a fix for this.

Comment: FWIW, it doesn't appear fixed for me. I'm using Gradle 2.3.3/AS 2.3.3, and I'm also getting it in the preview. I'm calling setup(Context, FragmentManager, int).